# Date and Time format processing

Tags: java, xpath

1. I am trying to format data using x-path, Which is in same .class
   file with location and publisher name. How can i take only that date
   and display. This is the Link

> http://www.deccanherald.com/content/431942/bjd-vice-president-expelled.html

2. Here is that .class which i need to separate and display only date
   London, Sep 20, 2014, DHNS:" . I used split("\,")[1]. But i am
   getting only Sep 20 as answer. How can i get whole Sep 20, 2014.
   Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This example:

```
 String date="Sep 20, 2014, DHNS";
      String[] d=date.split("\\,");
      System.out.print(d[0]+d[1]);
```

---

**Update 2:**

Or you can use a regex to do this task

```
String date="Sep 20, 2014, DHNS";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w{3}\\s\\d{2}\\,\\s\\d{4}");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(date);
      m.find();
      System.out.println(m.group());
```